# Store an object to storage to database

Tags: angular, ionic2, storage

Hi I am trying to create a local database using ionic2 storage, i could save and retrieve a single name, but i dont know how to store an object.

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
    import { File } from 'ionic-native';
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    myData
    export class LoginPage {

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
                    public navParams: NavParams,
                    public storage: Storage ) {}    

            var myData= {
                            name: "yokesh",
                            phone: "00000000",
                            country: "country_state_sometihing",
                            email: "yoke@lksdjfljs.come"
                        }



setData(){
    console.log("set data");
   this.storage.set('userObj', JSON.stringify(this.myData));
   this.getData();
}


getData(){ 
    this.storage.get('userObj').then((data) => {
        console.log("get data", JSON.parse(data));

    });
```

i tried this but it shows my previous data, previously i set data like this

```
this.storage.set('name', 'yoke');
```

when i update the code with object i could able to get only "yoke" but not that object, so could some one help me to store object and retrieve it using storage

Comment: what is your console.log prints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stringfy your object before your set it, and then parse it when you get it so:

```
this.storage.set('userObj', JSON.stringify(bj));

this.storage.get('userObj').then((data) => {
    console.log("myd data", JSON.parse(data));
});
```

Comment: Nice approach, but how to convert the JSON object to the original object?